# Export to PDF using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, export-to-pdf

I haven an angularjs app which has a table with pagination. This app makes a call to the REST API which returns the data in JSON format to my angular app. This data is represented in a table format with pagination. (Lets say the app)
I have a need to export this entire data to pdf.

So far I have used an approach which I found [here](https://medium.com/@darilldrems/angularjs-export-html-table-to-pdf-excel-or-doc-formats-bb741d06dfec#.knxbjljp9).

I have been successful in exporting to pdf, but only the first page gets exported and not the ones with pagination.

I have found many links with stackoverflow to export to pdf using angularjs. But none of them had information about handling the pagination part.

Can someone help me to get the entire table (which is displayed with pagination) to pdf ?
Any other approach would also be fine.

Comment: This is just way too broad. You're going to want to at least attempt different approaches and discuss them, providing code that worked partially or didn't work at all. Otherwise, you're just asking someone to write a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. How I solved it was, I created a different .html page that would print out the whole table(no pagination because what you are using table export only prints what's in the DOM). So from your controller you can send your $scope.tableData to the new .html page, print the table, download the file and close the html page. Yeah, it requires opening a new tab and after downloading it you can auto close.

My code looked something like

`$window.localStorage['tableData'] = JSON.stringify($scope.tableData);
 $window.open('#/download');`   and in the same controller I had

```
if ($location.path() === '/download')...//download function and 
$window.close();
```

I used $window.localStorage to get the data to the new tab because my data was pretty big, I don't know if it's smart or not to use that but it was a solution at the time.